# Splitting file with sed into two files

Tags: php, regex, sed

I have a file of around 250M, which I want to split into two using the
`sed` command in ubuntu.

The line from which I wan to split is like:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `captcha_log`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `captcha_log`
```

The second file should include the above string.

Comment: And what does `php` do here?

Comment: Sorry if it can done with some `php` command and not SED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`csplit`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#csplit-invocation) tool for this:

```
pattern='DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `captcha_log`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `captcha_log`'
csplit infile /"$pattern"/
```

If you really want to use sed, you could do it in two steps:

```
pattern='DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `captcha_log`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `captcha_log`'
sed -n "/$pattern/q;p" infile > outfile1
sed -n "/$pattern/,\$p" infile > outfile2
```

`-n` prevents printing as the default action; `/$pattern/q` exits as soon as the pattern line is reached, and `p` is executed for each line before that.

The second command just uses an address range, from the pattern line to the last one `$`. Because the command is double quoted to get `$pattern` in, the `$` for the last line has to be escaped, `\$`.

Or you could do a single pass with awk:

```
pattern='DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `captcha_log`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `captcha_log`'
awk -v pattern="$pattern" '$0 == pattern { ++flag }
                           flag { print > "outfile2"; next }
                           { print > "outfile1" }' infile
```

The first pattern checks if the line matches our split line and increments a flag if so; the second line checks if the flag if set, and if so, prints to the second output file and skips the last pattern/action; the third action is executed if the flag is not set and prints to the first output line.

Comment: I am trying to do with CS split - but I am getting the error like - `$ pattern='DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `core_url_rewrite`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `core_url_rewrite`' csplit cupolasd_currentdb.sql /"$pattern"/
csplit: `/DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `core_url_rewrite`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `core_url_rewrite`/': match not found
265438046`

Comment: @Joshi Maybe there is a typo in the line you posted. Is there, for example, really no space between `\`captcha_log\`` and `CREATE TABLE`? Or a semicolon?

Comment: Ok I run the grep command - `grep -c "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS \`core_url_rewrite\`` and get the result found as 1. So do I need to escape the backticks ``` in cssplit as well.

Comment: ok I run the command(cssplit) both way that is escapting backticks wtih a backslash and without escaping it. In both the cases first file is 0 bytes and the second file is the full size of the file. surely I am missing something

Comment: @Joshi No, escaping is not the problem. What if you search for your whole expression with grep?

Comment: If I am searching the whole wide expression with grep without escaping then I am getting - command not found `core_url_rewrite` and if am escaping then the result is 0

Comment: @Joshi You have to single quote when searching with grep or use `grep -F`

Comment: Grep is working fine in finding the string I am using in cssplit. But CSSPLIT is not splitting correctly. - 
0
265438046

Comment: Thank for your help. I managed to do it with line number with your suggested CSPLIT.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135532/discussion-between-benjamin-w-and-joshi).